# Error: An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested. SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo un sp el cual quiero almacenar dentro de una tabla temporal, ya sea una variable de tabla o tabla temporal, en ambos casos, me marca este error:

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

Este es mi código que estoy generando para almacenar el sp, cabe mencionarles que el problema no es con el sp, sino en la forma de almacenarlo. El código del sp no se los agrego por que esta muy extenso.

Espero y me puedan ayudar

```
declare @tempo table
(
    CeEmplazamiento varchar(50),
    TotalGeneral decimal,
    TotGral decimal
)

INSERT into @tempo
exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Diciembre'
```

El sp, me genera cálculos finales que me arroja al final.

```
CeEmplazamiento    TotalGeneral       TotGral
Celaya             76.500000          81.000000
Coecillo           79.000000          81.000000
Irapuato           77.500000          81.000000
León Sur           85.750000          81.000000
Los Reyes          0.000000           81.000000
Oriente León       86.250000          81.000000
```

Hay algo que también me gustaría agregar, lo que estoy intentando es que en el misma tabla se almacenen 2 VECES el resultado del sp.

Ejemplo:

```
INSERT into @tempo
exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Diciembre'
exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Enero'
```

Comment: por favor agrega la etiqueta del motor de base de datos y la versión que estás usando

Comment: Con tu pregunta editada, el error es claro. Simplemente debes hacer `INSERT` dos veces. `INSERT INTO @tempo exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Diciembre';` y luego de nuevo `INSERT INTO @tempo exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Enero';`

Comment: De hecho ya lo he hecho, así, se me olvido agregar el otro insert a la pregunta, pero, realmente eso ya lo había hecho anteriormente.

Comment: Por favor postea la pregunta tal cuál es. No podemos estar adivinando tu problema si vas cambiando el código

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente es un error muy habitual y tiene que ver con una restricción de **SQL Server**: solo puede haber una única sentencia `INSERT; EXEC` activa, en tu caso hay dos

```
INSERT into @tempo
exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Diciembre'
INSERT into @tempo
exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Enero'
```

Para resolver esta limitación hay una técnica sencilla, debes crear una tabla temporal de sesión, por ejemplo `#tempo` antes y llenar la misma desde el `sp_telemetria_safety_mensual`

Algo así

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_telemetria_safety_mensual @mes varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO #Tempo VALUES ('Celaya', 76.500000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO #Tempo VALUES ('Coecillo', 79.000000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO #Tempo VALUES ('Irapuato', 77.500000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO #Tempo VALUES ('León Sur', 85.750000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO #Tempo VALUES ('Los Reyes', 0.000000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO #Tempo VALUES ('Oriente León', 86.250000, 81.000000)

END

GO

CREATE TABLE #Tempo
(
    CeEmplazamiento varchar(50),
    TotalGeneral decimal,
    TotGral decimal
)   
GO

exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Diciembre'
exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Enero'

SELECT *
      FROM #Tempo

DROP PROCEDURE sp_telemetria_safety_mensual
DROP TABLE #Tempo
```

También te recomiendo está página [How to Share Data Between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

Comment: Ya lo resolvi de otra manera, tuve que utilizar variables de tabla. Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías comprobar el código del procedimiento almacenado.

Este ejemplo funciona perfectamente en SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_telemetria_safety_mensual @mes varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @tempINT table
(
    CeEmplazamiento varchar(50),
    TotalGeneral decimal,
    TotGral decimal
)   


INSERT INTO @tempINT VALUES ('Celaya', 76.500000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO @tempINT VALUES ('Coecillo', 79.000000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO @tempINT VALUES ('Irapuato', 77.500000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO @tempINT VALUES ('León Sur', 85.750000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO @tempINT VALUES ('Los Reyes', 0.000000, 81.000000)
INSERT INTO @tempINT VALUES ('Oriente León', 86.250000, 81.000000)

SELECT * FROM @tempINT

END
GO


declare @tempo table
(
    CeEmplazamiento varchar(50),
    TotalGeneral decimal,
    TotGral decimal
)

INSERT into @tempo
exec sp_telemetria_safety_mensual 'Diciembre'

SELECT * FROM @tempo

DROP PROCEDURE sp_telemetria_safety_mensual
```

Por otra parte deberías evitar utilizar el prefijo sp_ para tus procedimientos almacenados.

El prefijo sp no significa "stored procedure" sino "special" e indica a SQL Server que se trata de un procedimiento almacenado de sistema que debe buscar en la base de datos master. Si no lo encuentra lo buscará en la base de datos actual.

Esto puede provocar:

- Problemas de rendimiento al tener que buscar primero en la base de datos master sin necesidad
- Problemas de ambigüedad si en futuras versiones se incluye en SQL Server un procedimiento almacenado con el mismo nombre
- Problemas de claridad de código dado que alguien podría interpretar que se trata de un procedimiento de sistema en lugar de uno de usuario de la propia base de datos

Comment: Hay algo que me gustaría mencionarles, estoy intentando almacenar 2 veces el resultado del sp en la misma tabla. Ahí es cuando me marca el error.